# Take a screenshot out of app: Android Studio

Tags: android, view, bitmap, screenshot

Im developing an app that takes a screenshot when certain event is detected (while my app is minimized).
Im using this code to create the bitmap:

```
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + fecha + ".jpg";                              
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();                   
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

It actually takes a screenshot, but the problem is that it takes my minimized app view, and not what I am looking at screen at that moment.

Someone know how can I take a picture of what I am looking at screen?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?, i have the same problem, does someone know how to solve it?